# How to tell react.js NOT to reconcile or interfere from a certain element?

Tags: dom, d3.js, svg, reactjs

One of my components has a `div` element into which I would like to spill and handle/mutate my own DOM - without React interfering.

I am using d3.js for that manual DOM manipulation, and no I am not looking for react-d3 solutions, I need plain d3 in there.

All works well for me, except the reacts console warnings:

`` warning.js:44Warning: Unknown prop `xmlns` on <svg> tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details, see ``

and

`warning.js:44 Warning: Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?`

So It complains about me using `class` instead of `className` or about having some html attributes which are not react style etc..

I'd like to tell React that from this component and below, it shouldn’t interfere, I will manage the DOM below this component manually.

Code looks something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';
import SomeD3CustomComp from '../some-d3-custom-comp.js';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
   this.injectChart();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
   this.injectChart();
  }

  injectChart() {
    const comp = findDOMNode(this.refs.nonReactContainer);
    const { chart } = this.props;
    const { shouldRender, data } = chart;
    if (shouldRender) {
      SomeD3CustomComp.render(comp, data);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { chart, someOtherData } = this.props;
    const { shouldRender } = chart;
    return(
      <article>
        {
          shouldRender &&
          <div className="non-react-element" ref="nonReactContainer"></div>
        }
        <div className="react-element">{someOtherData}</div>
      </article>
    );
  }
}
```

---

### Update:

The suggestion of returning `false` on `shouldComponentUpdate` doesnt take away the error messages I have stated above, maybe because of the fact that `shouldComponentUpdate` happens only when there is an update - after the first inject on `componentDidMount`.

Another problem with that approach is that if return `false` code never gets to the render method where more logic is implemented such as in the example above where I check if to render the container non react element. This is the way I simply remove all previously injected elements, in the previous state.

So I am still looking for help with that...

---

### Solved!

false alarm :/ just found out that those warning messages were related to a different part of the code. Was a strange coincidence from the time this new feature was developed and some older problem. Conclusion: look harder at the warning messages! 
So this integration with d3 actually works nice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - Ignore subnodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24864947/react-ignore-subnodes)